# Cannot Open user default database. Login Failed Visual Studio 2019 for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

First of all, I am new to SQL Server, I always use PostgreSQL as a database, but now I am doing some maintenance of an application that persists on SQL Server, so here I am. I am trying to debug a very large stored procedured. First I tried on SSMS v18, but according to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221349/how-to-add-the-debug-button-to-ssms-v18) I have to use Visual Studio, in which I am also new. I follow the instructions and try to connect to the database, but after I hit a new query I get this modal window:

[image: modal window error]

I find it weird that I can see the database tables, views and stored procedures, but am unabled to create queries. So I am thinking it is a silly configuration thing I am missing.

[image: visible tables]

I would appreciate the help, I have spent the whole day reading tutorials, but nothing works.

Comment: BTW i can make queries on DBEAVER, but unfortunaly it doesnt have a debugger for SQLSERVER.

Comment: The link you point to says to use Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.  They're two different products.

Comment: Check the logs on the server, and get the real error. If you don't understand it, then post that in your question.